# Pre-multiply by excluding NA in R

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
covar1 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
covar2 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
covar3 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
covar4 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
covar5 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(covar1,covar2,covar3,covar4,covar5))
names(df) <- c("covar1","covar2","covar3","covar4","covar5")
```

And these are my 3 models with parameters each coresponding to covariate as in `df`

```
model0 <- data.frame(covar1=4,covar5=7)
model1 <- data.frame(covar1=2,covar3=5,covar4=3)
model2 <- data.frame(covar1=2,covar2=5,covar3=3,covar5=7)
```

Now, I would like to choose model0-2 and premultiply with corresponding row from `df`. The rows of df which do not meet the matching criteria would give `NA`.

The intentition is to always use the longest model out of the 3 avaiable. So if the row matches the 4 covariate model = model2, that `df` row should be premultiplied with the model2 if there isn't match should try model1 or model0 the shortes.

Desired output:

```
      covar1 covar2 covar3 covar4 covar5 Output Model
 1      NA      2      3     NA     NA     NA
 2       1     NA      2      2      2     18    m1    # (1*2)+(2*5)+(2*3)=18
 3       3      1      2      1      1     21    m2    # (1*3)+(1*5)+(3*2)+(7*1)=21
 4      NA      1     NA      3      2     NA          # (1*2)+(2*5)+(2*3)=18
 ..
 ..
```

Now, I'm not going to write what I have tried as this would include even more information, which usually SO users don't like. For something like this there may be even package out there. Any hint or help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when making a data.frame, don't use this `as.data.frame`/`cbind` combination. Just use

```
df <- data.frame(covar1,covar2,covar3,covar4,covar5)
```

That will also set the names appropriately. I'm not sure where people pick up with `cbind` method but it's not a good habit.

Anyway, getting to your actual problem. It would be best to store your models in a list (longest to shortest). This will make processing easier

```
models <- list(m2=model2, m1=model1, m0=model0)
```

Now, we can do through the data frame and see which model has the most overlap with non-missing covariate values. First i calcualte the overlap and then choose the best model for each row

```
mmatch <- sapply(models, function(m) rowSums(!is.na(df[,names(m)]))/ncol(m))
wmodel <- apply(mmatch,1,which.max)
```

Now that I know the best model for each group (well, specifically it's index in the models list) I will split the data.frame based on the best match, do the multiplication, and then rejoin the data.

```
out<-unsplit(Map(function(m,d,n) 
    {cbind(d, Output=rowSums(d[,names(m)]*m[1,,drop=T], na.rm=T),
         Model=n, stringsAsFactors=F)
    }, 
    models, 
    split(df, wmodel), 
    names(models)), 
wmodel)
```

This will return

```
   covar1 covar2 covar3 covar4 covar5 Output Model
1       1      3      3      3     NA     26    m1
2       3      1      2      3      1     24    m2
3       1      2      2      2      1     25    m2
4       3      2      3      3      1     32    m2
5       3     NA      2     NA     NA     NA    m1
6      NA      3      2      1     NA     NA    m1
7       2     NA      2      3     NA     23    m1
8       3     NA      2     NA      1     19    m0
9       2      1      1      1      1     19    m2
10      1      3     NA     NA      3     25    m0
```

I'm not sure the desired output you showed actually used the seed you specified because I got different values.