# Unsplit data.frame with condition in R

Tags: r

I'm using unsplit to convert list of data.frame back into data.frame;

List I'm having problem with:

```
$m3
    model1  model2   model3   Output Model
 3  0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m4
 4  0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m4
 5  0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m4

$m2
    model1    model2 model3 Output  Model
 1  0.200    0.099     NA     NA      m3
 2  0.356    0.25      NA     NA      m3

$m1
    model1      model2   model3  Output Model
 1     0.200    0.099     0.3     0.9    m1
 2     0.35     0.252     0.4     0.9    m1
```

to unsplit I use this approach:

```
unsplit(x,c(3,3,1,1,1))
```

The intention is to get the `$m3` and `$m1` and not `$m3` and `$m2`. It seems that it just takes 
it in the order. So I would like to extract form the list (unlist) if the `Output` is not `NA`. 
How can I do this?

For sample data and related question see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577297/pre-multiply-by-excluding-na-in-r)

EDIT: Desired output:

```
    model1  model2   model3   Output Model
 1  0.200   0.099    0.3      0.9     m1      # and not m3 from $m2
 2  0.35    0.252    0.4      0.9     m1      # and not m3 from $m2
 3  0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m4
 4  0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m4
 5  0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you where `l` is your list:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l, FUN=function(x) if(!any(is.na(x$Output))){x}))
```

Reproducible example:

```
m3 <- read.table(header=T, text='
                     model1  model2   model3   Output Model
   0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m4
   0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m4
   0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m4
                 ')

m2 <- read.table(header=T, text='
       model1    model2 model3 Output  Model
 0.200    0.099     NA     NA      m3
 0.356    0.25      NA     NA      m3
                 ')


m1 <- read.table(header=T, text='
                     model1  model2   model3   Output Model
 0.200    0.099     0.3     0.9    m1
 0.35     0.252     0.4     0.9    m1
                 ')

l <- list(m3=m3, m2=m2, m1=m1)

do.call(rbind, lapply(l, FUN=function(x) if(!any(is.na(x$Output))){x}))
> do.call(rbind, lapply(l, FUN=function(x) if(!any(is.na(x$Output))){x}))
     model1 model2 model3 Output Model
m3.1  0.130  0.113   0.18   0.40    m4
m3.2  0.157  0.110   0.21   0.50    m4
m3.3  0.058  0.030   0.18   0.46    m4
m1.1  0.200  0.099   0.30   0.90    m1
m1.2  0.350  0.252   0.40   0.90    m1
```

Answer (score 3):

I would vectorize the whole thing using `data.table`s very efficient `rbindlist` function combined with `complete.cases`

Assuming `l` from @cdetermans answer

```
library(data.table)
l <- rbindlist(l)
l[complete.cases(l), ] 
#    model1 model2 model3 Output Model
# 1:  0.130  0.113   0.18   0.40    m4
# 2:  0.157  0.110   0.21   0.50    m4
# 3:  0.058  0.030   0.18   0.46    m4
# 4:  0.200  0.099   0.30   0.90    m1
# 5:  0.350  0.252   0.40   0.90    m1
```