# Working with unsplit in R

Tags: r

This question is related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893120/unsplit-data-frame-with-condition-in-r) I have accepted too early as it doesn't solve what I actually needed.

The data looks more like this:

```
m4 <- read.table(header=T, text='
model1  model2   model3   Output Model
0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m4
0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m4
0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m4 ')

m3 <- read.table(header=T, text='
model1  model2   model3   Output Model
0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m3
0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m3
0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m3 ')

m2 <- read.table(header=T, text='
model1    model2 model3 Output  Model
0.200    0.099     NA     NA      m3
0.356    0.25      NA     NA      m3 ')

m1 <- read.table(header=T, text='
model1  model2   model3   Output Model
0.200    0.099     0.3     0.9    m1
0.35     0.252     0.4     0.9    m1 ')

models <- list(m4=m4, m3=m3, m2=m2, m1=m1)
```

**EDIT1:**

Desired result with unsplit:

```
model1  model2   model3   Output Model
0.200   0.099     0.3     0.9     m1
0.35    0.252     0.4     0.9     m1
0.13    0.113    0.18     0.4     m4
0.157   0.11     0.21     0.50    m4
0.058   0.03     0.18     0.46    m4
```

The desired soulution must be within `unsplit`...that means: 4th list entry (4,4)== means 2 rows of the 4th list entry, likewise (1,1,1) means first list entry with 3 rows.

**EDIT2**: Can someone point me where I can read more about `unsplit`? I cannot find anything even in books.

**EDIT 3:**  Now suppose that I have this helper function to provide me the indexing for extraction from the list:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1),5,4)
mat[1,1] <- 0.66; mat[1,2] <- 0.33; mat[1,3] <- 0.33
mat[2,1] <- .66; mat[2,2] <- 0.33; mat[2,3] <- 0.33
extract <- apply(as.matrix(mat),1,which.max)
```

This suppose to work:

```
unsplit(models, extract)
```

Answer (score 1):

`unsplit` doesn't do what you think it does.  To extract the 1st and 4th models, you just need your usual square bracket indexing.

```
models[c("m1", "m4")]
```

or

```
models[c(1, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need something else not extracting single list entry. Please see edit1-3. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rbind` and just access the elements with `[`:

```
do.call(rbind, models[c("m1", "m4")])


     model1 model2 model3 Output Model
m1.1  0.200  0.099   0.30   0.90    m1
m1.2  0.350  0.252   0.40   0.90    m1
m4.1  0.130  0.113   0.18   0.40    m4
m4.2  0.157  0.110   0.21   0.50    m4
m4.3  0.058  0.030   0.18   0.46    m4
```

Comment: I would really need unsplit solution instead, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use `unsplit`?  That function is designed to reverse the operation of a call to `split`, and it's pretty painful to use.  There are better ways of manipulating your dataset.

Comment: I know, but I have a function which gives me the rows which to extract from list. I have to work from there. Please see the edit 1-3.